# error in updating user profile

Tags: php, mysql

I having problem in updating user when user is login

I revive error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET registered_users (fullName='test1',mobileNumber='123123',password='8eaaf462' at line 1sorry ,Pleae go to nearest NPC to register.
Notice: Undefined variable: sql_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\bicycleTheft\test5\php\edit_data.php on line 43

manageparticulars.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();


$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Update Data From MySql - By Cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<h1>Edit Particulars</h1>

<div id="body">
    <div id="content">
    <table align="center" width="100%">


            <tr>
            <td>Full Name</td>
            <td><?php echo $row["fullName"]; ?></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Mobile Number</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mobileNumber']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><?php echo $row ['password']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Postal Code</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['postalCode']; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td><a href="edit_data.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><img src="b_edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a></td>
           </tr>

    </table>
    </div>
</div>


</center>
</body>
</html>
```

edit_data.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
$reg_user = new USER();

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
if(isset($_GET['edit_id']))
{
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM registered_users WHERE userID=:uid".$_GET['edit_id']);


}
if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
{
    // variables for input data

    $fullName = $_POST['fullName'];

    $mobileNumber = $_POST['mobileNumber'];

    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $postalCode = $_POST['postalCode'];
    // variables for input data

    // sql query for update data into database

        if($reg_user->updateUser($fullName,$mobileNumber,$password,$address,$postalCode))
        {

            echo"good";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "sorry ,Pleae go to nearest NPC to register.";
        }
    // sql query for update data into database

    // sql query execution function
    if(mysql_query($sql_query))
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Data Are Updated Successfully');
        window.location.href='home.php';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('error occured while updating data');
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    // sql query execution function
}
if(isset($_POST['btn-cancel']))
{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PHP Update Data From MySql - By Cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<center>

<div id="header">
    <div id="content">
    <label>PHP PHP Update Data From MySql - By Cleartuts</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <div id="content">
    <form method="post">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
    <td>Full Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="full Name" value="<?php echo $row['fullName']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Mobile Number</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mobileNumber" placeholder="mobile Number" value="<?php echo $row['mobileNumber']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Blk 123 Ang Mo kio Ave 1 #12-112" value="<?php echo $row['address']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>Postal Code</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="postalCode" placeholder="123456" value="<?php echo $row['postalCode']; ?>" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <button type="submit" name="btn-update"><strong>UPDATE</strong></button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn-cancel"><strong>Cancel</strong></button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>



</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In first file 9th row you have double semicolon: `$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;`

Comment: can you please also share the function `updateUser()` ?

Comment: Also second file 9th row double semicolon...

Comment: i have posted as answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
public function updateUser($fullName,$mobileNumber,$password,$address,$postalCode)
    {
        try
        {
            $password = md5($password);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE SET  registered_users (fullName=:fullName,mobileNumber=:mobileNumber,password=:password,address=:address,postalCode=:postalCode)");


            $stmt->bindparam(":fullName",$fullName);

            $stmt->bindparam(":mobileNumber",$mobileNumber);

            $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":address",$address);
            $stmt->bindparam(":postalCode",$postalCode);



            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```